# Sitecore: Programmatically trigger reindexing of related content

Tags: lucene, sitecore

In my sitecore instance, I have content for 2 templates, *Product* and *Product Category*. The products have a multilist that link to the *Product Category* as lookups. The Products also have an indexing computed field setup that precomputes some data based on selected Product Categories. So when a user changes a Product, Sitecore's indexing strategy indexes the Product with the computed field.

My issue is, when a user changes the data in the Product Category, I want Sitecore to reindex all of the related products. I'm not sure how to do this. I do not see any hook where I could detect that a Product Category is being indexed, so I could programmatically trigger an index to products

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve using the `indexing.getDependencies` pipeline. Add a processor to it - your custom class should derive from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetDependencies.BaseProcessor` and override `Process(GetDependenciesArgs context)`.

In this function you can get your IndexedItem and add, based on this information, other items to the Dependencies. These dependencies will be indexed as well. Benefit of this way of working is that the dependent items will be indexed in the same job, instead of calling new jobs to update them.

Just be aware of the performance hit this could cause if badly written as this code will be called on all indexes. Get out of the function as soon as you can if not applicable.

Some known issues about this pipeline can be found on the [kb](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/116076).

Comment: Moe info here: http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/06/sitecore-index-dependencies.html

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a custom `OnItemSave` handler which will check if the template of the changed item has the **ProductCategory** template, and will problematically trigger the index update.

To only reindex the changed items, you can pickup the related Products and register them in the HistoryEngine by using the `HistoryEngine.RegisterItem` method:

`Sitecore.Context.Database.Engines.HistoryEngine.RegisterItemSaved(myItem, new ItemChanges(myItem));`

Some useful instructions how to create `OnItemSave` handler can be found here: https://naveedahmad.co.uk/2011/11/02/sitecore-extending-onitemsave-handler/

Comment: how would this work on the web database / CD? Using your solution, after a smart publish, the onItemSave wouldn't be triggered on the ProductCategories

Comment: Yes, but you only use the OnItemSave to register the change in the sitecore HistoryEngine. Shouldn't the smart publish pick that up and trigger the reindex?

Comment: i like your suggestion, specially as its so lite. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could add or change one of existing index update strategies. (*configuration\sitecore\contentSearch\indexConfigurations\indexUpdateStrategies* configuration node)

As example you could take

> Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.SynchronousStrategy

One thing, you need to change

```
public void Run(EventArgs args, bool rebuildDescendants)
```

method. *args* contains changed item reference. All that you need, trigger update of index for related items.

After having custom update strategy you should add it to your index, *strategies* configuration node.